# Is it possible to use an AWS CodeStar connection via the SDK to pull code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-codebuild, aws-codestar

Is it possible to use an existing AWS CodeStar Connection in code to pull a repo outside of using it in CodePipeline?

I have a CodeBuild project that I want to trigger via an automated process with different environment variable values, and the only way I see of being able to pull the code into the CodeBuild execution is a `git pull` in the build container. The pull would require a Personal Access Token that would in turn need to be updated periodically.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, goal is to use the connection you have set up in AWS (CodeStar) in order to run something like

```
git clone aws-codestar-connection-url
```

Disclaimer, I have not tried this myself.
Have a look if this gives a hint or two. Suggests it is (***or was***) possible:
https://pooya.io/how-to-access-github-and-bitbucket-using-aws-codestar/

**Important note** - CodeStar itself was discontinued, so the above suggestion may be out and connections might by fully integrated to